# Disable sql stdouts in grails 2.4.4

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have tried show_sql, logSql , check all my log4j configuration - hibernate is set to error.

I am not sure what is missing

I even tried to get jdbcservice from `sessionFactory.serviceRegistry"`  and found `jdbcServices.getSqlStatementLogger().isLogToStdout()` set to false.

any pointers ?

Comment: what kind of sql statements are being logged? Have you looked for the `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder` loggers in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: i am seeing queries like  "Hibernate: select distinct key0_.TTL as col_0_0_ from KEY key0_" in ivptomcat-stdout.2016-01-18.log


logging is still same grails default    


error   'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
 ...
 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
 'org.hibernate',
 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

Comment: Have you set `logSql = true` in **config/DataSrouce.groovy**?